# Grunt minification fails for AuthService

Tags: angularjs, bundling-and-minification, grunt-contrib-uglify

Note: please see EDIT 2 shorter example of issue

This is my AuthService minified code:

```
var Services;
!function(a) {
    var b = function() {
        function a(a, b, c) {
            var d = this;
            d.$q = a, d.$http = b, d.$rootScope = c;
        }
        return a.prototype.login = function(a) {
        //....
        }, a.AuthServiceFactory = function(b, c, d) {
            return new a(b, c, d);
        }, a;
    }();
    a.AuthService = b, b.$inject = [ "$q", "$http", "$rootScope" ], angular.module("eucngts").factory("AuthService", b.AuthServiceFactory);
}(Services || (Services = {}));
```

And this is my controller minified code where I get error:

```
var Controllers;
!function(a) {
    var b = function() {
        function a(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
        //...
        }
        //...
    }();
    a.HeaderController = b, b.$inject = [ "$scope", "$location", "AuthService", "$rootScope", "$modal", "$timeout" ], 
    angular.module("eucngts").controller("HeaderController", b);
}(Controllers || (Controllers = {}));
```

Error message is:

```
Unknown provider: bProvider <- b <- AuthService
```

Otherwise when I comment lines that use this service, my other controllers and services works fine.

The orders of lines in source file seems fine

My concatenated and none minified js file works fine as well.

What I could be reason that I get this error.

**EDIT**

When I put none uglified code instead of uglified one, it works fine

```
var Services;
(function (Services) {
    var AuthService = (function () {
        function AuthService($q, $http, $rootScope) {
            var self = this;
            self.$q = $q;
            self.$http = $http;
            self.$rootScope = $rootScope;
        }
        //...
        AuthService.AuthServiceFactory = function ($q, $http, $rootScope) {
            return new AuthService($q, $http, $rootScope);
        };
        return AuthService;
    })();
    Services.AuthService = AuthService;
    AuthService.$inject = ['$q', '$http', '$rootScope'];
    angular.module('eucngts').factory('AuthService', AuthService.AuthServiceFactory);
})(Services || (Services = {}));
```

EDIT 2:
This is complete code of another service that I could not define that service which is shorter and easier to inspect:

```
var Services;

!function(a) {
    var xxx = function() {
        function a(a, zzz) {
            var c = this;
            this.request = function(a) {
                a.headers = a.headers || {};
                var zzz = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authorizationData"));
                return zzz && (a.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + zzz.token), a;
            }, this.responseError = function(a) {
                var zzz = c;
                return 401 === a.status && (localStorage.removeItem("authorizationData"), zzz.$location.path("/login")), 
                zzz.$q.reject(a);
            };
            var d = this;
            d.$location = a, d.$q = zzz;
        }
        return a.AuthInterceptorServiceFactory = function(kkk, c) {
            return new a(kkk, c);
        }, a;
    }();
    a.AuthInterceptorService = xxx, xxx.$inject = [ "$location", "$q" ], angular.module("eucngts").factory("AuthInterceptorService", xxx.AuthInterceptorServiceFactory);
}(Services || (Services = {}));
```

none-uglified code:

```
var Services;
(function (Services) {
    var AuthInterceptorService = (function () {
        function AuthInterceptorService($location, $q) {
            var _this = this;
            this.request = function (config) {
                var self = _this;
                config.headers = config.headers || {};
                var authData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authorizationData'));
                if (authData) {
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
                }
                return config;
            };
            this.responseError = function (rejection) {
                var self = _this;
                if (rejection.status === 401) {
                    localStorage.removeItem('authorizationData');
                    self.$location.path('/login');
                }
                return self.$q.reject(rejection);
            };
            var self = this;
            self.$location = $location;
            self.$q = $q;
        }
        AuthInterceptorService.AuthInterceptorServiceFactory = function ($location, $q) {
            return new AuthInterceptorService($location, $q);
        };
        return AuthInterceptorService;
    })();
    Services.AuthInterceptorService = AuthInterceptorService;
    AuthInterceptorService.$inject = ['$location', '$q'];
    angular.module('eucngts').factory('AuthInterceptorService', AuthInterceptorService.AuthInterceptorServiceFactory);
})(Services || (Services = {}));
```

which says:

```
Unknown provider: kkkProvider <- kkk <- AuthInterceptorService <- $http <- $templateRequest <- $compile
```

Comment: You are injecting `AuthService` but that only gets defined within `Service` and you don't seem to be injecting that anywhere?

Comment: Do you mean this one?  `var Services;`

Comment: Sorry yes that was a typo!

Comment: service is `b.AuthServiceFactory`, but your $inject is on `b`

Comment: @YOU What should I replace in my code then?

Comment: if you $inject on xxx, you need to use `.factory("AuthInterceptorService", xxx);` or $inject on `xxx.AuthInterceptorServiceFactory`

Comment: @YOU Now that's working, awesome. Thank a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer to my question with greate help of @YOU

My typescipt code for `AuthInterceptorService` class

```
module Services {
    export class AuthInterceptorService {
        $location: ng.ILocationService;
        $q: ng.IQService;
        constructor($location, $q) {
            var self = this;
            self.$location = $location;
            self.$q = $q;
        }
        //...
        static AuthInterceptorServiceFactory($location, $q) {   
            return new AuthInterceptorService($location, $q);
        }
    }
    AuthInterceptorService.$inject = ['$location', '$q'];
    angular.module('eucngts').factory('AuthInterceptorService', AuthInterceptorService.AuthInterceptorServiceFactory);   
}
```

When I update it to:

```
module Services {
    export class AuthInterceptorService {
        $location: ng.ILocationService;
        $q: ng.IQService;
        constructor($location, $q) {
            var self = this;
            self.$location = $location;
            self.$q = $q;
        }
        //..
        static AuthInterceptorServiceFactory($location, $q) {   
            return new AuthInterceptorService($location, $q);
        }
    }
    AuthInterceptorService.AuthInterceptorServiceFactory.$inject = ['$location', '$q'];
    angular.module('eucngts').factory('AuthInterceptorService', AuthInterceptorService.AuthInterceptorServiceFactory);
}
```

It works as expected